# Create article url structure with categories and date?

Tags: php, html, url, get, structure

I would like to create a blog where I can post articles and categorise them. So my final goal would be that the url of an individual post would be something like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/health/2013/08/25/lorem-ipsum-dolor
                      ------            -----------------
                        |                       |
                     category                 title
```

Now, while I know how to generate a link like that, I am not quite sure what to do with this when I actually click this link. How do I read all the way back to category ? What is the conventional way to process this code ? (If I knew how to extract category, year, month and day)I would read the given data and make requests against my database. Is that the correct way ?

## EDIT:

I have found something that would give me the URI.

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

I would then go ahead and extract the needed parts. However is that a good way to do it ?

Comment: OK, and you don't want to create uris like `http://www.mysite.com/health?2013/08/25/lorem-ipsum-dolor` or `http://www.mysite.com/health#2013/08/25/lorem-ipsum-dolor`?

Comment: @MrLister No, exactly like above. I have updated my answer. I am still not sure if that would be best practise...

Comment: try: http://www.jamesnorthard.com/extract-or-find-a-directory-from-url-using-php/